# DeleteButton code for deleting the data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#

[image]

I have a form name "AddNewUnitForm" through this I am saving data in a SQL Server database. Please advice code for "DeleteButton" deleting the data from database by selected data of datagridview

`SaveButton` code is as under for the reference

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_UnitMasterInsertDetails", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Parameter
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UNITNAME", AddUnitTextBox.Text);

        //Open Connection
        conn.Open();

        // ExecuteReader (Select Statement)
        // ExecuteScalar (Select Statement)
        // ExecuteNoQuery (Insert, Update or Delete)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("ADDED SUCCESSFULLY", "Succesful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a stored procedure to delete records
2. use transactions to if there is a fall back, while deleting
3. your delete button code will be similar to the insert here you will be calling stored procedure for deleting, with key parameter to pass the stored procedure.
4. if you want to do soft delete make a column with flag `IsDeleted` and changes the flag when deleted